# R package MatchIt erroneous summary output

Tags: r, matching, summary

I am running coarsened exact matching (CEM) via the package MatchIt as a pre-processing step and want to use the matched data in further analyses. In looking at summary statistics for the matched data, I noticed that means extracted from the matched dataset differ from the MatchIt summary output. For example, using the lalonde dataset:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(doBy)
data(lalonde)

m.out <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + black + hispan + married + nodegree + re74 + re75, data = lalonde, method = "cem")
summary(m.out)   #Means from MatchIt summary output:

Summary of balance for matched data: 

             Means Treated   Means Control 
 age         21.5441         21.1781 
 educ        10.2941         10.3827 
 black       0.8676          0.8676 
 hispan      0.0588          0.0588 
 married     0.0441          0.0441 
 nodegree    0.6176          0.6176 
 re74        456.1345        622.8740 
 re75        350.6728        520.7135 

m.dat<-match.data(m.out)
ExtractedMeans<-summaryBy(age+educ+black+hispan+married+nodegree+re74+re75 ~ treat, data = m.dat, FUN=function(x) { c(Mean=mean(x)) } )
ExtractedMeans   #Means extracted manually from matched data:

treat         1          0 
age.Mean      21.544    19.628 
educ.Mean     10.294     9.7179 
black.Mean    0.8676    0.60256 
hispan.Mean   0.0588    0.10256 
married.Mean  0.0441    0.07692 
nodegree.Mean 0.6176    0.75641 
re74.Mean     456.13    609.61 
re75.Mean     350.67    464.22
```

The means for the control group extracted manually from the matched data are not consistent with the MatchIt summary output. Does anybody know what is going on here? I posted this question to the MatchIt gmane email list last week but have not received a response. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'doSummary' function is not using the weights. If you multiply the weights by the variable that you want to average, you will get the same average as the package displays. As an example, take your code and do this:

```
> tapply(m.dat$age, m.dat$treat, mean)
       0        1 
19.62821 21.54412

> tapply(m.dat$age*m.dat$weights, m.dat$treat, mean)
       0        1 
21.17811 21.54412
```

And so, they are equal the MatchIt results...

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification. It should be more obvious that the output stats MatchIt gives are weighted. I am using MatchIt as solely a pre-processing step, and not planning to use the weights in my regression analysis, so I need a good match without the weights.

Comment: A good idea then is to try another method instead of *cem*. I would suggest you the nearest neighbor method, but you have to try out and see which is working better, without discarding too many observations. For your example above, *nearest* seem to be working ok.

Comment: Yes, very good advice. Since I have multiple covariates I ended up matching based on propensity score using "nearest" and adjusting the caliper specification until I was satisfied with the match and the sample size. After matching, I checked the balance of each covariate using a slightly different formula than MatchIt's ((mean1-mean0)/sqrt(var1+var0), based on Imbens and Wooldridge 2008, "Recent developments in the econometrics of program evaluation"). I am happy with the resulting match.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the calipers are applied to the propensity score NOT to the individual variables.  So you can end up with individual matched pairs whose individual variables have very different values.